# How to change the server port from 3000?

Tags: npm, angular

I just ended the tutorial of Angular 2 and I can't find a way to change the localhost port from 3000 to 8000. In my `package.json` file there's the line `"start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "` that I believe is related but I'm not sure.

Comment: It was a real problem that I was having, it can be obvious for you, but I may have skip this part of the documentation. I think I expressed myself well because I had a perfect answer. But I would be glad to know why did you think I wasn't seriously expecting an answer to my question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can change it inside `bs-config.json` file as mentioned in the docs https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server#custom-configuration

For example,

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "files": ["./src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
}
```

Comment: I just had to take out the `src` from the files and baseDir. It was perfect.

Comment: Hi@Kalman, In my project setup there is no any bs-config.json  so how I can change my port number. can you please help me.
though, i have searched "port" or "3000" in my whole project but nothing like that in my project.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma create a new file at the root of project and add just a single entry for port (since you don't need others).

Answer (score 16):

Using Angular 4 and the cli that came with it I was able to start the server with `$npm start -- --port 8000`. That worked ok: `** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:8000, open your browser on http://localhost:8000 **`

Got the tip from [Here](https://github.com/erming/shout/issues/535)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

1-> Using File Default Config- Angular-cli comes from the ember-cli project. To run the application
   on specific port, create an .ember-cli file in the project root. Add
   your JSON config in there:

{
   "port": 1337
}

2->Using Command Line Tool
Run this command in Angular-Cli

> ng serve --port 1234

To change the port number permanently:

Goto

> node_modules/angular-cli/commands/server.js

Search for `var defaultPort = process.env.PORT || 4200;` (change 4200 to anything else you want).

Answer (score 3):

In `package.json` set the following command (example for running on port 82)

```
"start": "set PORT=82 && ng serve --ec=true"
```

then `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" --port 5000"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in the `webpack.dev.js` file in config folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `bs-config.json`, you can change the port inside the lite-server module. Go to `node_modules/lite-server/lib/config-defaults.js` in your project, then add the port in "modules.export" like this.

```
module.export {
    port :8000, // to any available port
    ...
}
```

Then you can restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

If want to change port number in angular 2 or 4 we just need to open .angular-cli.json file and we need to keep the code as like below

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }, 
"serve": {
      "port": 8080
    }

}
```