# Express server isn't running on my React production build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm

I have a React app made with create-react-app which I am trying to run on an express server. It works fine when running `npm start` but when running `npm run build` and then `serve -g build` I can only connect to port 5000 on localhost and not 8080 which I set up in the express server.

> server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
 return res.send('pong');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/remote', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.use('/api', jsonServer.router('./src/config.json'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

I have also setup my proxy and main

> package.json

```
"main": "server.js",
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: maybe check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440979/how-to-change-the-server-port-from-3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly said, `proxy` directive works well in development mode, with `npm start`.

Also, as you correctly said, `serve -g build` command, serves correctly your production build in localhost:5000.

For your main purpose, that is to serve your production build within your express server, you need to generate the production build with:

```
npm run build
```

And then serve it in one of your server endpoints, as follows:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/build')));
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('build/index.html'));
});
```

And don't forget to start your server with

```
node server.js
```

Comment: I believe I misunderstood how server.js worked but your post cleared it all up, thanks!